# Посоветуйте пожалуйста хороший курс по javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Посоветуйте пожалуйста хороший курс(или канал, или книгу...) по javafx

Comment: Исчерпывающая книга на английском Pro JavaFX 8.

Comment: вот хороший видеокурс для начинающих: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY2sQXGt2jo&list=PLEvI1OiL1F3ctezdKwvJnQK2f_H8U0HqK&index=40

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Хорошей литературы довольно мало.
Могу порекомендовать: Т.Машнин - "JavaFX 2.0 разработка RIA-приложений"